# Java : How to pick Latest 10 files from a Folder based on file creation Date?

Tags: java, performance, file

I have a Folder containing 10,000 images inside my Server  , where there can be Images present  starting from Current Date till last 2 Months .

Is it possible that i can pickup only the latest 10 files without having big performance issues?

Java : How to pick Latest 10 files from a Folder based on file creation Date??

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a Code Writing, Tutorial or Consulting Service](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/172496)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have say exactly as Nitin
But I understand you don't want the 100 000 images in memory

Would it be possible to modify the file names to include their creation date ?
E.g. picture765.jpeg -> 20120418_picture765.jpeg

If yes,
Use a FileFilter to retreive only a limited amount of files eg: today files
Store them in an ArrayList
You don't have 10 images? Keep looking for yesterday, then the day before, ...

Another way:
use two folders
One for your active pictures
The second for archives
Up to you to decide when to move pictures from one directory to another

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Create a `File` object pointing to the directory. use `listFiles()` to get an array of files in the directory. Sort it on `lastModified()` and you get what you need.

you can see this [reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot , but the Folder can contain atleast 10,0000 images ,  will it be not a performance issue ??

Comment: That may be a serious performance issue... What exactly you want to do?

Comment: Dont know if it is possible to create a .bat file and do `dir /p/o:-d` and send the output to a file. `/p` to pause the output to some 30 odd files and `/o:-d` to sort it new-old. With this you can read it from the file. But i really dont know about this. Try posting a new question

Comment: hey Nitin thanks for the concern , a user log on to my site , upload pictures and as part of display , i need to pick up only the last 10 files

Comment: I would suggest in this case maintain a log of files posted by the user. It keeps a log of user activity which always comes handy and will help you solve this issue relatively easily. Also if you can change the file names then you can use Hugues suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Get all the files, sort them by date, and take the last 10 elements.